# How do I get Google to index my 30 million pages?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I am releasing a website which has 30 million pages of content. (This isn't spam material).
It has a detail page for each of the 30 million places around the World.

e.g /mywebsite.com/id/country/city/street etc..

I assumed submitting a sitemap would get Google to index these pages, but I was mistaken, how can I achieve this?

Comment: How long has it been??

Comment: I haven't submitted it yet......

Comment: 1-3 months for the ones it sees as fresh/relevant, then up to a year for the rest of the spammy duplicates. Or....mostly never, since there are already so many local directories far ahead of you in the race for "Authority". Keep in mind, you need to split your sitemap up into pages of 50,0000 http://www.mugo.ca/Blog/Google-Sitemaps-for-big-sites-splitting-the-sitemap-into-multiple-files But even then it sounds like you are gonna need more indecies. I would suggest not even using a sitemap.